# Submit shows code when hosted

Tags: javascript, image, hosting, src

I have a quiz with values that are added to a sum which determines the image displayed but is only showing me my raw .js file when I click submit. I am hosting it and am not sure why it is showing me this. The previous function in the file work, since the validation works and is found in that file.

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



    <title></title>

    <meta name="author" content="Kenneth Dunn" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/random.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>


<div id="page">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1><a href="https://playoverwatch.com">Overwatch</a></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <h2 align="center">Overwatch Quiz</h2>
    <p>
      Hi there! This quiz is dedicated to one of my favorite games Overwatch!
    </p>
    <form action="js/random.js" method="post" name="quiz_form" onsubmit="owchar()">
      <p>
        <br>
        <input id='fName' name "first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name"   onblur="this.placeholder='First Name'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Use only letters'"  class="validate" />
        <img width="45px" height="45px"src='img/Q.png' id="fNameImg" />
      </p>


      <p>
        <br>
        <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name"  onblur="this.placeholder='Last Name'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Use only Letters'" class="validate"/>
        <img width="45px" height="45px" src='img/Q.png' id="last_nameImg"  />
      </p>


      <p>
        <br>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email"  placeholder="Email"  onblur="this.placeholder='Email'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Must contain @ '" class="validate" />
        <img  width="45px" height="45px" src='img/Q.png' id="emailImg"  />
      </p>


      <p>
        <br>
        <input id='phone' name="number"  type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" onblur="this.placeholder='Phone Number'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Must follow xxx-xxx-xxx '" class="validate" />
        <img  width="45px" height="45px" src='img/Q.png' id="phoneImg" />
      </p>


      <p>
        <br>
        <input id='sulley' name="sulley" type="sulley"  placeholder="Sulley Email" onblur="this.placeholder='Sulley Email Address'" onfocus="this.placeholder='Must contain ~ and https:// '"  class="validate"/>
        <img width="45px" height="45px" src='img/Q.png' id="sulleyImg" />
      </p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p>

        <h2>Find out which Overwatch character you are most like!</h2>


        <p>If you could pick what form to take in a fictional universe with magic and cool science what would you want to be?</p>

        <input type="radio" name="exist" value="1">Male(Human).
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="exist" value="2">Female(Human).
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="exist" value="3">An Animal or something crazy.

        <p>What is your preferred weapon to take on bad guys and defend yourself?</p>

        <input type="radio" name="weapon" value="1">Twin Shotguns for close range.
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="weapon" value="2">Twin pistols medium range.
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="weapon" value="3">An electro gun that schocks enemies into submission.

        <p>Which motivations most align with your own?
          <p>

            <input type="radio" name="idea" value="1">To become more powerful and to defeat those who would oppose me.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="idea" value="2">To explore the world and discover the unknown.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="idea" value="3">To protect my friends and those I care about.

            <p>What do you look like?</p>

            <input type="radio" name="look" value="1">Dark and mysterious black-hooded figure ,very edgy, like people in the Matix.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="look" value="2">Short and spunky British airforce pilot who can travel back in time.
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="look" value="3">I'm a large gorilla who likes to eat bananas and peanut butter and can sheild my friends from harm.


            <br>
            <br>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
          </p>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <h2 align="center" >Congratulations you got...</h2>
    <div id="character" align="center" height="499" width="281" >
        <img src="" id="character"/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
      <h2 align="center">Created by Kenneth Dunn </h2>

      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script src="js/random.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
 function validateData() {
      console.log(this);
      var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
      var email = [@];
      var tel = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/gm;
      var sulley = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/;

      var imgId = this.id + 'Img';
      var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
      console.log(img)
      var valid = false;

      if (this.type == 'text') {
        if (this.value.match(letters)) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }

      if (this.type == 'email') {
        if (this.value.match(email)) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }

      if (this.type == 'tel') {
        if (this.value.match(tel)) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }

      if (this.type == 'sulley') {
        if (this.value.match(sulley)) {
          valid = true;
        }
      }


      if (valid) {
        img.src = "img/check.png";
      } else {
        img.src = "img/redx.png";
      }


    }

    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("validate");
    for(i=0 ; i<els.length ; i++){
      els[i].addEventListener("change", validateData, false);
    }

    function owchar(){
        var sum = 0;
        var w = document.forms["quiz_form"]["exist"].value;
        sum+=w;
        var q = document.forms["quiz_form"]["weapon"].value;
        sum+=q;
        var r = document.forms["quiz_form"]["idea"].value;
        sum+=r;
        var g = document.forms["quiz_form"]["look"].value;
        sum+=g;

        if (sum>1 && sum<6){
            document.getElementById("character").src="img/reaper.png";
                return false;
        }
        else if (sum>6 && sum<9){
            document.getElementById("character").src="img/tracer.jpeg";
                return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("character").src="img/winston.png";
                return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: a quick note I have a folder called folder where the html file is stored, and then 3 sub folders called css, img, and js, where the css, img and js are stored respectively.

Comment: why are you posting to a JS file?

Comment: The first part is form validation the second is the value associated with the answers will give me my sum, which I am using to determine which img to change the img id("character").

Comment: Yes, but a JS file is not going to run when you submit the form to it.  If you want to run JavaScript for a validation, than you should include the script on the page and bind the onsubmit event.

Comment: I did not know that, if I used a button would it operate the same way? This is for an assignment, must use external js

Comment: Did you teacher/professor teach you how to add an external js file to the page?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: if you mean inline script , I know about that, I'm not supposed to though for some reason

Comment: I said nothing about an inline script and the link shows external js file.

Comment: Sorry, I am very stupid right now, long day. I will look at what you linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is defined as:

```
<form action="js/random.js" method="post" name="quiz_form" onsubmit="owchar()">
```

The `action` tells the browser where to go after submission, not what js file to look in. Javascript uses a shared global scope, meaning that all JS files use the same global scope, even ones built directly into the page. Because of this Javascript awesomeness -- or weirdness (depending on your views) -- you don't need to specify where the code is that you want to run, you just have to load the code (using a `<script>` tag).

**TL;DR;**

Change this line so that it looks like the following example:

```
<form name="quiz_form" onsubmit="owchar()">
```